# Enabling JSON using jersey and grizzly

Tags: java, json, jersey, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I am playing with Jersey hosted with Grizzly and want to be able to consume and produce JSON, however I am getting 500 from the server in get request and media type unsupported in POST
my server code is

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
    rc.packages("RestServer.controllers");

    final Map<String, Object> initParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "rest");
    initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");

    rc.addProperties(initParams);

    webServer = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, rc, false);
```

my POJO is:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Dummy {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Dummy(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and controller

```
@Path("/Dummies")
public class DummyController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response get() {
        System.out.println("Get");
        return Response.status(Status.OK)
            .entity(new Dummy(-1, "hello"))
            .build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response AddDummy(Dummy dummy) {
        return Response.status(Status.CREATED).entity(dummy).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You're using Jersey 2. In Jersey 2, there *is* no `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature` and `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages`, so you can get rid of those.

To enable JSON to/from POJO, we need a `MessageBodyWriter/MessageBodyReader`(see more [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html)). Fortunately, we don't need to write these ourselves. You just need a dependency (see [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json)).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This depedency will pull in the required Jackson `MessageBodyReader/MessageBodyWriter`. Then just configure it

```
resourceConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

Comment: God knows why Jersey keeps changing their method names, and why this is not accepted as the best answer... works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: I created an archetype jersey application with Jersey 2.27. You can enable json by adding (uncommenting) the Maven dependency org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-binding and don't even have to register the reader/writer.