# JAX-RS service always replies with 415 Unsupported Media Type error to POST requests

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I know (quite) similar questions was asked numerous times, but solutions to them didn't work for me.

I'm creating a REST service with JAX-RS and Jersey 2 which consumes json beans from post requests, it looks like this:

```
@Path("auth")
public class AuthService {
@Inject
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@POST
@Path("login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(ApiCredentials credentials){
    try {
        authenticationManager.login(credentials);
        return Response.ok().build();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
    }
}
```

and runs in a programmatically configured embedded tomcat

```
public class WebServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException, LifecycleException, MalformedURLException{
    String webappDirLocation = "webapp/";
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    // Define port number for the web application
    String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if (webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8089";
    }
    // Bind the port to Tomcat server
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

    // Define a web application context.
    Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/tomcatembedded", new File(
            webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

    Tomcat.addServlet(context, "jersey-container-servlet", resourceConfig());
    context.addServletMapping("/rest/*", "jersey-container-servlet");


    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}
private static ServletContainer resourceConfig(){
    return new ServletContainer(
            new ResourceConfig(
                new ResourceLoader().getClasses()
            )
            .register(new ApplicationBinder()) //binds AuthenticationManager
            .packages("com.dockerhosting.api.rest.auth", "com.dockerhosting.rest.auth")
    );
}
}
```

When I trying to post a json serialized ApiCredentials to the rest service it replies

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.22 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Unsupported Media Type</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.22</h3></body></html>
```

I tried to add mimepull to the classpath of the service and to add Content-Type header to the client, but it didn't change anything. The clinet code is:

```
JerseyClient client = new JerseyClientBuilder().build();

    JerseyWebTarget target = client.target("http://192.168.122.156:8089/tomcatembedded/rest/auth/login");
    Response response = target.request()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(credentials, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Change `ApiCredentials credentials` to `String credentials` and see if it works. If it does, then you're missing a JSON provider. I'm curious about this though, because if you didn't have a provider then the client would fail without even making the request, give the `credentials` on the client is not a String (can't see)

Comment: If that's the problem, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28467586/2587435) if you're using Maven, if not [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29791894/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet I changed credentials type to `String` and strangely it works. I added genson 1.3, jersey-client and org.json:json to the classpath, changed credentials back to `ApiCredentials` and it still replies with the same error. BTW client is a separate programm with a different set of dependencies (now after I added genson, jersey-client and json dependencies are almost the same with the the service) compared to service

Comment: I don't use Genson or Json.org. I don't know if json.org has a jax-rs provider. I use Jackson. For jacskon, use the first link. If Genson does have a provider, then you may need to register it in the resource config

Comment: When I say provider, I mean an implementation of `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`. You may want to example the source

Comment: @peeskillet I explicitely registered `JacksonJsonProvider` with `ResourceConfig` and it solved the problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comment (just to have an answer... see comments for discussion)

> **Artem Zhirkov**: I explicitely registered `JacksonJsonProvider` with ResourceConfig and it solved the problem

Comment: It's bizarre, I can't scientifically explain why this solved my issue (of a jersey-serving .jar accepting PUT when run locally but returning 415 when run from a docker container) yet there it is; my issue was resolved by `resourceConfig.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);`